# React + Material UI - Best way to prevent child tree from remount when toggling parent theme

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, components, react-router-dom

**Background**

I wanted to follow Material UI's implementation of toggling UI's dark/light mode theme. [Link.](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#ToggleColorMode.js)

I have encapsulated its implementation into a custom hook that returns theme-related properties when called. This is called at my `App()` level.

```
import { createContext, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';


export default function useTheme() {

    const ColorModeContext = createContext({ toggleColorMode: () => {}, mode: null})
    const [ mode, setMode ] = useState('light')

    const colorMode = useMemo(
        () => ({
            toggleColorMode : () => {
              setMode((prevMode) => (prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'))  
            },
        })
    , [])  


    // recreate theme everytime mode changes
    const appTheme = useMemo( () => (createTheme({
        palette: {
          mode: mode,
          primary: ...
        },
      })), [mode])
    
    
    
    return {
        ColorModeContext,
        colorMode,
        ThemeProvider,
        appTheme
    }
}
```

At the `App()` level, I have it returns the following App Component:

```
...
    const {
        ColorModeContext,
        colorMode,
        ThemeProvider,
        appTheme
    } = useTheme()

    // another custom hook to return auth related properties
    const {
        AuthContext,
        authed,
        ...
    } = useAuth()
   return (
     <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={appTheme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <AuthContext.Provider value=...>
                    <Box>
                        <Router>
                            <Header 
                                ColorModeContext={ColorModeContext}
                                theme={appTheme}
                                authed={authed}
                                ...
                            /> 
                            <Routes>
                                <Route 
                                    path="/" 
                                    element={
                                        <Signin AuthContext={AuthContext} />
                                    } 
                                />
                                <Route 
                                    path="/create" 
                                    element={
                                        <RequiredAuth authed={authed}>
                                            <Create />
                                        </RequiredAuth>
                                    } 
                                />
                                <Route 
                                    path="/query" 
                                    element={
                                        <RequiredAuth authed={authed}>
                                            <Query />
                                        </RequiredAuth>
                                    } 
                                />
                            </Routes>
                            ...
                        </Router>
                    </Box>
                </AuthContext.Provider>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </ColorModeContext.Provider>
)
```

Lastly, in my header component (as the context consumer, to have the toggle callback function exposed in the header)

```
...
const { ColorModeContext, authed, ... } = props;

return (
        <ColorModeContext.Consumer>
            {
                ({toggleColorMode}) => (
                    <Box>
                        <AppBar position="static" enableColorOnDark>
                            <Toolbar>
                              ...
                                <IconButton
                                  size="small"
                                  onClick={toggleColorMode}
                                  color="inherit"
                                >
                                   {
                                       theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 
                                          <LightModeIcon /> : <Brightness3Icon />
                                   }
                               </IconButton>
                            ...                   

                            </Toolbar>
                        </AppBar>
                    </Box>
                )
            }
        </ColorModeContext.Consumer>
)
```

**ISSUE**

Toggling the theme works, however, If I am inside my component `<Create />` or `<Query />` and I toggle the theme, the entire component tree  (Create or Query) is remounted, and all states within the component refreshed to its initial state.

Basically, if I am inside my `<Create />` component, and I am filling out the create form, which the values of the form are maintained by `useState`, as soon as I toggle the theme, all of the values resets to their initial value (which was passed into the `useState` hook)

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to prevent this remount from happening? I know it's not just rerendering the component, because the state is reinitialized. If it's not a rerender issue, then would `React.memo` work here? If not, what would be the best way to toggle theme (context at a parent component lvl) while inside a child component without having the component remount.

---

Adding a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/remount-sample-m178oh?file=/src/App.js) link. It should include a simple example of the issue that I am having. The child component remounts (as logged by the Child's `useEffect`) when I toggle parent's theme mode.

Comment: Why are the `useTheme` and `useAuth` hooks returning the context provider components? Normally you would import the provider and use the hooks to access the provided context value in a child component. I don't know if this is related to the issue you are asking about but I don't think it's helping you at all.

Comment: @DrewReese thx for the response; I'm sorry I am quite new to React, I am still trying to find the best way to organize/separate logic and components. So you're saying that I should be using my custom hook that should return context values at the children component level? I could have also just imported ThemeProvider as well.  I think instead, I use hooks at the most outter component level, and if needed pass it down to children components via props. Not sure if thats okay.

Comment: @DrewReese But yeah, the issue described still exists, once I toggle the theme, which is passed in the `<ThemeProvider theme={theme} />`, all of its child components are remounted, and all of its states are reinitialized (which is an undesired behavior). I have also looked into possible explanations, I think maybe React Router recreating its Route element causing all of its element and child components recreated and therefore remounted. Unfortunately, I have yet to find a good implementation of separating Route element logic and the ThemeProvider to test out the hypothesis :/

Comment: Could you create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code here that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Thank you sir, added a link for demo, the counter state keeps resetting as the theme gets toggled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useTheme` hook should return the provided context value, not the context itself. This is recreating a context provider and remounting children.

Example:

useTheme

```
import { createContext, useState, useMemo, useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const ColorModeContext = createContext({
  toggleColorMode: () => {},
  mode: null
});

const ColorModeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");

  const toggleColorMode = () => {
    setMode((prevMode) => (prevMode === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
  };

  // recreate theme everytime mode changes
  const appTheme = useMemo(
    () =>
      createTheme({
        palette: {
          mode
        }
      }),
    [mode]
  );

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider
      value={{
        toggleColorMode,
        mode
      }}
    >
      <ThemeProvider theme={appTheme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => useContext(ColorModeContext);

export default ColorModeContextProvider;
```

App

Import the new `ColorModeContextProvider` provider component to provide the theme and color mode contexts, and the `useTheme` hook to be used in the `Header` component to access the `toggleColorMode` callback.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import ColorModeContextProvider, { useTheme } from "./useTheme";
import useAuth from "./useAuth";

function App() {
  const { AuthContext, authed, user, login, logout } = useAuth();

  return (
    <ColorModeContextProvider>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authed, user, login, logout }}>
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
          <Header />
        </Container>
        <Child />
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </ColorModeContextProvider>
  );
}

function Header() {
  const { toggleColorMode } = useTheme();
  return <button onClick={toggleColorMode}>ToggleTheme</button>;
}

function Child() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("Child component unmounting");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter((count) => count + 1);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit react-material-ui-best-way-to-prevent-child-tree-from-remount-when-toggling]

The `useAuth` hook needs a similar refactoring applied to it as well.

Comment: Shortly after I updated the question with the link, I was messing around with the codesandbox and did notice it was the Context Provider that was giving the issue, but still wasn't sure why. Thank you for your clarification. So would it be safe to say that when the theme state is updated, the App component is re-rendered, and my old custom hooks (useTheme and useAuth) get called everytime and therefore returning a new instance of the each of their Context Provider, causing the entire dom tree underneath to be remounted?

Comment: @Rennitbaby Yes, I think it was the new React context each render that was the main issue.

Comment: Sorry, follow-up question, how come in your answer, having the custom hook returning the component `ColorModeContextProvider ` containing the entire context element including ThemeProvider, and its children, solved the issue. Shouldn't the context `ColorModeContext` be a new instance when useTheme is called again during the re-render?

Comment: @Rennitbaby No, you want the created `ColorModeContext` context to be a stable reference, so the `.Provider` React component it's providing is *also* a stable Reference. The `useTheme` hook should only be used to access the provided context value.

Comment: A stable reference meaning the place you do the `createContext` call? Mine was within the `useTheme` function, which in theroy is computed every render?  Which makes it not stable, is that right? haha im sorry for the extra questions.

Comment: @Rennitbaby A stable reference, meaning the object it refers to doesn't change for the life of the React component that is using it, `App` in this case. Yes, in your code each time the hooks were called they created a new React context object reference.